# Validating emails in file with batch

Tags: regex, bash

I have a file with emails and I need to validate them.

The sequence is:

1. First name.
2. Dot.
3. Last name.
4. Number (optional - for same names).
5. static string domain(@utp.ac.pa).

I wrote this:

```
egrep -E [a-z]\.+[a-z][0-9]*@["utp.ac.pa"] test.txt
```

It should match this email: "anell.zheng@utp.ac.pa"

But it is also matching:

- test4@utp.ac.pa
- 2anell@utp.ac.pa

Although they don't follow the sequence. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `egrep` and `-E` are redundant.  (`egrep` == `grep -E`)

Comment: Is the number always preceded by an underscore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't even match the first email. If I understand your requirements correctly, this should work:

```
[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*@utp\.ac\.pa
```

- Note that to match a dot, it needs to be escaped (i.e., `\.`) because `.` [matches any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).
- You can get rid of `A-Z` if you don't want to match upper-case letters.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/fWKaeh/3).

Let me know if this isn't what you want.

Comment: Hi Ahmed i have made a little change. I need to match "anell.zheng@utp.ac.pa" so i change a little of your regex to  egrep [A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*@utp\.ac\.pa      But it still matching the others

Comment: I see your edit. This will still match the changed email. Isn't the optional number and underscore still a requirement?

Comment: The optional num is required but not the underscore

Comment: Well, I just updated my answer accordingly. Please try it [online](https://regex101.com/r/fWKaeh/3) first and let me know what exactly doesn't work as expected.

Comment: In the online it throws the correct answer but when i use it in batch it is throwing the email: test4@utp.ac.pa

Comment: I've tried it with bash using `egrep "[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*@utp\.ac\.pa" test.txt` and it works just fine. I see that you accepted the answer, does that mean it works with you now?

Comment: i think is my pc issue

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `^[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+(?:_\d+)*@utp\.ac\.pa$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tANHD9/1)

Regex Details:

- ^ asserts position at start of a line
  Match a single character present in the list below [A-Za-z]+
  . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
  Match a single character present in the list below [A-Za-z]+

  - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    Non-capturing group (?:_\d+)*
  - Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    _ matches the character _ literally (case sensitive)
    \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
  - Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    @utp matches the characters @utp literally (case sensitive)
    . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
    ac matches the characters ac literally (case sensitive)
    . matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
    pa matches the characters pa literally (case sensitive)
    $ asserts position at the end of a line

Comment: This will not match "anell.zheng04@utp.ac.pa" (without `_`).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, I went with the sample email that OP has given